# XSL transform output to javascript

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml :

```
<Data>
<Revenue>
  <revDate>2015-05-31 00:00:00.000</revDate>
  <source>1</source>
  <currencyId>50</currencyId>
  ...
</Revenue>
<Revenue>
  ...
</Revenue>
</Data>
```

I need to populate an html template using xsl transformation.
The logic is dependent on whether the 'Source' node is 1 or not.

I am trapping the source node in the first row of the revenue data in the xsl as follows -

```
<xsl:variable name="sourceID">
    <xsl:value-of select="Data/revenue[@source][1]/text()"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

This is then passed onto a javascript function -

```
<a href=".." onClick="javascript:return isSourceLinked('{sourceID}');">
```

However,this does not work as the null/blank check on the parameter sourceID always fails(irrespective of whether it contains value or not).

What am i doing wrong - how do I trap the node value?

Comment: your xpath seems wrong... revenue => R capital, @source is attribute not element although in your xml source is element.

Comment: How are you generating the Javascript? Or "passing" the XSL variableinto Javascript? You are missing a step here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for sourceID is wrong. Try instead ...

```
<xsl:variable name="sourceID" select="Data/Revenue/source[1]/text()" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't `revenue` be `Revenue` instead?

Comment: @DavidDossot: Yes. Tnx.